# How to see what process is using GPU?

Tags: nvidia, graphics, gpu

I've seen that my GPU is using a lot of it's computing power. It is often above 70%, never lower than 50% (measured directly after a reboot)

```
14:06:34 ~/  $ gpustat
laptop0                                       Wed Mar  9 14:09:11 2022  
[0] NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2060 with Max-Q Design | 56'C,  74 % |  1369 /  5934 MB
```

But this says only something about the GPU usage as a whole. I've no idea which process is using the GPU.

`cpu-stat` has the option to list the processes as well but this only displays the memory usage:

```
14:10:38 ~/  $ gpustat -cp
laptop0                                       Wed Mar  9 14:10:44 2022  
[0] NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2060 with Max-Q Design | 54'C,  50 % |  1358 /  5934 MB |
Xorg/4904(843M) gnome-shell/5106(163M) mattermost-desktop/5640(55M) jetbrains-toolbox/6338(22M) 
brave/8888(269M)
```

I've tried and failed to find a tool that displays the GPU usages per process. There are a lot of programs to display the GPU usage, but only as a whole and not per process.

I've tried:

- `glances`
- `cpu-stat`
- `nvidia-smi`

Maybe with another parameter that I missed? Maybe it is not possible because of the proprietary character of NVidia?

Comment: Hey, did you happen to find this out, because I'd love to know how to do this

Comment: Nope, still no idea

Answer (score 9):

The `nvidia-smi` tool can access the GPU and query information. For example:

```shell
nvidia-smi --query-compute-apps=pid --format=csv,noheader
```

This returns the `pid` of apps currently running. It kind of works, with possible caveats shown below.

```shell
> nvidia-smi
Fri Nov 11 02:08:18 2022
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 520.61.05    Driver Version: 520.61.05    CUDA Version: 11.8     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce ...  On   | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 50%   61C    P2   301W / 350W |  23683MiB / 24576MiB |     69%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A   2747694      C   python                          23680MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+

> nvidia-smi --query-compute-apps pid --format=csv,noheader
2747694
```

Easy enough because there is only one process. On a machine with several processes, it can be surprising:

```shell
> nvidia-smi
Fri Nov 11 11:10:38 2022
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 510.85.02    Driver Version: 510.85.02    CUDA Version: 11.6     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce ...  On   | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   32C    P8    N/A /  N/A |   3546MiB /  4096MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      1515      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                 28MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      1724      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell               67MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      2806      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                296MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      3025      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell               22MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      3569      G   ...AAAAAAAAA= --shared-files       10MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A     12329      G   /usr/lib/firefox/firefox           34MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A     13708      G   ...oken=16615837409882897952        8MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A     28690      C   ...abcdef/venv/bin/python3.7     3069MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+

> nvidia-smi --query-compute-apps=pid --format=csv,noheader
28690
```

It returns only the process I am interested in (lucky), of type C. This may be surprising but [makes sense](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54750627/2050), as C stands for compute, and the query filter is for compute (G stands for graphics).